# Root privilege is needed when using kinect

Tags: ubuntu, kinect, ros, openni

I have encountered a problem recently that can be described as : Root privilege is needed whenever a program needs kinect to run.

My tool chain setup is: ubuntu14 + ros indigo + opencv_2.4.11 + openni_1.5.7.10 + primesense_5.1.2.1 + kinect_v1

The phenomenons are as follows:

1. When I try to check out the kinect output through openni NiViewer, if I run NiViewer without 'sudo', I will get the following message

   One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

   Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: The device is not connected!

   Press any key to continue . . .

   But kinect functions normally once I add the 'sudo' to open NiViewer.
2. I try to run an opencv sample "openni_capture.cpp" in qt, during compiling, it shows error that permission denied when accessing libopenni.so, I check the properties of that file and it shows 'none' for users other than owner. So I give other users read-only access and compile went through. But when I run the built executable, it shows another error:

   Can not open a capture object.
   CvCapture_OpenNI::CvCapture_OpenNI : Failed to enumerate production trees: Can't create any node of the requested type!

   until now I have the feeling that maybe everything related to kinect needs root privilege, so I navigate to the folder that contains the executable and manually run it with 'sudo', then kinect is working again.

I know I can avoid this problem by logging in as root(which is against by many people), but I really want to know what's going on. And I remember that before I install ROS, I didn't have to use 'sudo' to open NiViewer. Does ROS change the ubuntu system somehow and caused this, or is there other reason? THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an access privileges problem and maybe to run in user mode, you need to add yourself to the UNIX ‘video’ group (see this [explanation](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Webcam-HOWTO/dev-intro.html))

```
sudo adduser $USER video
```

Then log out and back in. Reboot is not necessary, just plug cycle the Kinect (if already connected, unplug and plug back in), and retry. Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks Vtik, I solved this with a brutal method, I simply searched for all files in the usr/lib that are related to openni, and give them read-only access collectively, then the problem disappeared. Still, I will mark your answer accepted, hope it can help others with the same problem.